# variable decimal places in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How do you make it so that all calculations in the DB compute to a pre-specified # of decimal places?  Say I have three tables with the following fields

### Table1

- A int
- B decimal(18, 3)

### Table2

- A int
- B decimal (18, 2)
- C decimal (18, 3)

### Table3

- A int
- Precision int

Now I need to change it so that all my calculations are based on what precision is set for A in Table3.  I started by converting all my decimals to decimal (30, 10) to allow for higher precisions if specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your results in a `CAST` statement to set them to the desired precision.  I.e.:

`SELECT CAST((<query>) AS int) AS Result`

Comment: thanks, this is what I was thinking of...my result needs to be a decimal, so it should be SELECT CAST((<query>) AS decimal(18, desired-precision)) AS Result, right?

Comment: Exactly.  I put `int` since you said in  your example `A`, all of which are `int` in your sample data.

Comment: so it would be fine to put a variable for desired-precision? Something like decimal(18, @precision)?

Comment: Just clarifying, what you meant is that I should store everything as is in the table, and just before reporting results to the UI, round it based on the specified precision?

Comment: @Prabhu - Correct.  This is probably the simplest way to get what you want.

Comment: @JNK It seems that your solution doesn't work, as a simple example
`declare @decimals int
set @decimals = 5
select cast(15.8 as Decimal(38,@decimals))`
And it says "Incorrect syntax near @deciamls Expecting INTEGER"

Comment: @RezaRahmati I never said to use a variable as the precision, I was responding to the pattern of wrapping your results in a `CAST` before returning it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [ROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) function in a stored procedure that first retrieves the precision from your `Table3` table.

Comment: So you're saying store everything as is in the table, and just before reporting to the UI, round it off based on the specified precision?

Comment: I'm saying create a stored procedure that retrieves the desired precision first and uses it in the ROUND function to round it off to that precision. All of this contained in a stored procedure that you create. You could use the CAST (instead of ROUND) function as has already been suggested.